# Empty result when using cursor.fetchall() or cursor.fetchone()

Tags: python, mysql, database

There is a simple table in MySQL

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name_1 |
| ... | ... |

And I'm trying to get the **id** (it's the primary key by the way) number by **name**, using this code

```py
import mysql.connector

# ...create connection
def get_id(name):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = """SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = %s"""
    try:
        cursor.executemany(query, [name])
        # connection.commit() - it didn't help, and I use connection.autocommit = True
        result = cursor.fetchall()  # or cursor.fetchone()
        return result
    except Error as err:
        print(f"The error '{err}' occurred")
```

But this returns only an empty list [] or None (depending on the fetch method).

I have already tried changing the code, inserting checks like:

```py
if result != None:
    return(result)
```

And using `cursor.stored_results()`. It doesn't help.

Also, if using `SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = "name_1"` in MySQL Workbench, it outputs the correct id. So, I don't understand what the problem might be...

Comment: The MySQL docs and the Python standard are not clear (at least for me) what happens with result sets from `executemany`. This method seems to be not suitable for SELECT statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SELECT statement won't work with the `exectutemany()`.

Change call to executemany() to execute() with tuple as the second argument.

```
query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = %s"
cursor.execute(query, (name,))
```

For executemany() examples, see [API docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html)